# Change image in JLabel in function

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I've got the funcion SetCover(), to set the icon in a JLabel. Here's the function:

```
public void SetCover(String URL)
{
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(URL);
    lbl_cover.setIcon(null);
    lbl_cover.setIcon(image);
    lbl_cover.revalidate();
}
```

But the code doens't change the image. The value of the function does change, but not the picture. For exaple:

```
SetCover("C:\Picture_1")
SetCover("C:\Picture_2")
```

The picture is always 'picture_1', but if I first enter:

```
SetCover("C:\Picture_2")
SetCover("C:\Picture_1")
```

than the picture will be 2, so it doens't change. Any idea how this comes? Any help?

Thanks :)

Comment: There's more pertinent information that you're not telling us. Consider doing some debugging first to try to isolate the problem, and then show us the relevant code.

Comment: The problem is that it doens't change the icon, I've got no problems with text.

Comment: Our problem is that the code you're showing us in know way tells what could possibly be wrong. **Again** if you want to fix this thing, you're going to have to do some debugging. Period.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would rewrite the function?

Comment: You don't get the point: ***The problem is not in the code you've posted above!*** Re-writing it will serve no purpose. You **first** have to find your problem and that involves **debugging**. And yes, as per camickr, an [sscce](http://sscce.org) would help a lot.

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few scenario's come to mind:

- You are blocking the AWT Event Thread. (eg, you are calling SetCover in a long loop)
- Your reference `lbl_cover` is not pointing the the actual label you excpect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the `ImageIcon` to `null` before changing it. Generally, you should be updating swing components through an EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) but after you set the `ImageIcon`, try `repaint()`ing the `JLabel` before `revalidate()`ing.

Also, make sure the `ImageIcon` isn't null; there is a possibility that your path does not exist.

Comment: The path exists for sure, he swapped the initial image and it worked.

Comment: There should be no need to revalidate or repaint the JLabel itself after swapping icons, although the container may need to be revalidated if the label size changes appreciably.

Comment: Can you give an example of the EDT? I've never heard of it, neither used it.

Comment: `try repaint()ing the JLabel before revalidate()ing.` - don't try random stuff if you don't know the reason for doing it. The order is always revalidate() and then repaint(). The point of revalidate() is to lay out a component or its parent container at is proper size/location. Then repaint() can paint the component. `Can you give an example of the EDT?` - search the forum for examples and more information when you hear about a concept you don't understand. This is part of learning.